# How to troubleshooot Windows choice loop?

Tags: loops, batch-file, variables, if-statement

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:adapterloopstart
echo.
echo please enter the type of adapter you would like to create
echo 1. Host-Only
echo 2. Internal
echo.

set ADAPTYPE=
choice /C:12
if ERRORLEVEL 2 set ADAPTYPE=intnet
goto adapterconfirm
if ERRORLEVEL 1 set ADAPTYPE=hostonly
goto adapterconfirm
REM If you got here, it wasn't 1, 2
goto adapterloopstart
echo %ADAPTYPE%

:adapterconfirm
echo %ADAPTYPE%
set confirmadapter=
set /p confirmadapter=Do you wish to create a "%ADAPTYPE%" network (y,n):
if not '%confirmadapter%'=='' set confirmadapter=%confirmadapter:~0,1%
if '%confirmadapter%'=='y' goto adapterend
if '%confirmadapter%'=='n' goto adapterloopstart
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
:adapterend
```

the above code gives the following string:

> Do you wish to create a "" network (y,n):

It does not display the variable.

How can I fix this so I know it saved the variable with correct choice for when I wish to re-run this code later so I can get feedback of what's going on?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the variable `confirmadapter` with your last `ECHO` command?  You never set a variable named `choice`. Also , the command to check if errorlevel is 1, will never run because you have a `GOTO` before it.  The choice command also only allows you to enter one of the choice options. You do not need the goto command to get back to the adapter loop start.

Comment: Not sure why you would use choice for one input but not the other.  The choice command is the perfect solution for YES/NO question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will simplify your logic a bit. Use the choice command to your advantage.

```
@echo off
:adapterloopstart
cls
echo.
echo Please enter the type of adapter you would like to create
echo 1. Host-Only
echo 2. Internal
echo.

set "ADAPTYPE="
choice /C:12
if ERRORLEVEL 1 set "ADAPTYPE=hostonly"
if ERRORLEVEL 2 set "ADAPTYPE=intnet"

choice /M "Do you wish to create a '%ADAPTYPE%' network:"

if errorlevel 2 goto adapterloopstart

:adapterend
```